# Why the Content is not written into the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file, file-handling

```
def save(text,translated_text):
    file_path=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = [('text files','*.txt')])
    file_name=file_path.name
    filename=file_name.split("/")[-1]
    f= open(filename,'w')
    f.writelines(fr"{text}")
    f.writelines(fr"{translated_text}")
    f.close()
    f_label=tk.Label(new_window,text="Your file has been saved as "+file_path.name)
    f_label.pack()
```

What wrong with the above code.
The file is created.
But there is no text in the file(The file is Empty)

I tried to write to the file a piece of text,but the text does not get written in the file.

Comment: are `text` and `translated_text` proper lists or just a string?  Just wondering as you are passing them to `writelines()`

Comment: @JonSG Even if they're lists, when you format them in the f-string it returns a string. But `writelines()` accepts any sequence, so it will treat as string like a list of characters, so it should still write it to the file.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct directory for the file? You're removing the directory part of the filename when you use `file_name.split("/")[-1]`. Why are you doing that, when the dialog returns the file in the directory that the user chose?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, It worked after I deleted the line 'file_name.split("/")[-1]".